# Error al tratar de mostrar los datos de 2 tablas usando php y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

Estoy teniendo un error al tratar de mostrar los datos de dos tablas.
Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Frank\principal.php on line 45

```
            <?php
            $consulta= "SELECT CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido) AS nombre, numOrden, problema,  modelo,  fecha, estado FROM orden, usuario WHERE orden.idUsuario=usuario.id ";

                foreach ($conex->query($consulta) as $row){ ?> 
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['numOrden']?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['modelo']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['problema']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: **¿Seguro que `$conex->query($consulta)` devuelve un array?** En cualquier caso, acostumbra a usar variables y a depurarlas. Ejemplo: `$arrDatos=$conex->query($consulta);` Para depurar: `var_dump($arrDatos);` y si es efectivamente un array, entonces: `foreach ($arrDatos as $row){//resto del código}`

Comment: Hola Francisco! Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero terminar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y de paso ganar tu primera medalla! También puedes ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: ese error me ha salido cuando no tengo información guardada en el array, ahi el problema es que el foreach este tratando de manejar una variable que no puede.

Comment: Intenta con `foreach ($conex->query($consulta)->fetch_assoc() as $row){` o recibe antes el resultado de la sentencia y luego aplicas el fetch_assoc